# PhpMyAdmin & MAMP : internal relations missing

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp

I have installed MAMP on two computers (Mac OS X.10.5). I have created the pmadb's using the supplied create_tables.sql

On one computer, when I open "Relation view", there is only the "foreign key constraints" part, not the "internal relations" part. The "choose column to display is missing too, as you can see on attached screen cap :
[image]
[image]

It's the same version of MAMP (3.4), the same version of PhpMyAdmin (4.4.10), and the same config file, as it's the default from MAMP. By default the pmadb section of the conf is empty, but it work as it on one machine. I tried anyway to fill it, but it doesn't change anything.

As far as I can now, all of the other additionnal features of PhpMyAmdin are working correctly.

My config.inc :

```
<?php
/* $Id: config.inc.php,v 2.52 2005/03/16 17:22:08 lem9 Exp $ */
if (!isset($old_error_reporting)) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    @ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}
$cfg['VersionCheck'] = FALSE;
$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = '';
$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri_DisableWarning'] = TRUE;
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning']  = TRUE;
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '';

/**
 * Server(s) configuration
 */
$i = 0;
// The $cfg['Servers'] array starts with $cfg['Servers'][1].  Do not use $cfg['Servers'][0].
// You can disable a server config entry by setting host to ''.
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'localhost'; // MySQL hostname or IP address
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3306';          // MySQL port - leave blank for default port
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';          // Path to the socket - leave blank for default socket
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';       // How to connect to MySQL server ('tcp' or 'socket')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';     // The php MySQL extension to use ('mysql' or 'mysqli')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;       // Use compressed protocol for the MySQL connection
                                                    // (requires PHP >= 4.3.0)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = '';          // MySQL control user settings
                                                    // (this user must have read-only
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = '';          // access to the "mysql/user"
                                                    // and "mysql/db" tables).
                                                    // The controluser is also
                                                    // used for all relational
                                                    // features (pmadb)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';    // Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)?
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';      // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'root';          // MySQL password (only needed
                                                    // with 'config' auth_type)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db']       = '';          // If set to a db-name, only
                                                    // this db is displayed in left frame
                                                    // It may also be an array of db-names, where sorting order is relevant.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']       = '';          // Verbose name for this host - leave blank to show the hostname

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']         = '';          // Database used for Relation, Bookmark and PDF Features
                                                    // (see scripts/create_tables.sql)
                                                    //   - leave blank for no support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'phpmyadmin'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = '';          // Bookmark table
                                                    //   - leave blank for no bookmark support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_bookmark'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation']      = '';          // table to describe the relation between links (see doc)
                                                    //   - leave blank for no relation-links support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_relation'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info']    = '';          // table to describe the display fields
                                                    //   - leave blank for no display fields support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_table_info'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords']  = '';          // table to describe the tables position for the PDF schema
                                                    //   - leave blank for no PDF schema support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_table_coords'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages']     = '';          // table to describe pages of relationpdf
                                                    //   - leave blank if you don't want to use this
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_pdf_pages'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info']   = '';          // table to store column information
                                                    //   - leave blank for no column comments/mime types
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_column_info'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history']       = '';          // table to store SQL history
                                                    //   - leave blank for no SQL query history
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_history'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose_check'] = TRUE;        // set to FALSE if you know that your pma_* tables
                                                    // are up to date. This prevents compatibility
                                                    // checks and thereby increases performance.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot']     = TRUE;        // whether to allow root login
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['order']           // Host authentication order, leave blank to not use
                                     = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules']           // Host authentication rules, leave blank for defaults
                                     = array();


$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;              // Default server (0 = no default server)
$cfg['Server']        = '';
unset($cfg['Servers'][0]);


/**
 * Other core phpMyAdmin settings
 */
$cfg['OBGzip']                  = 'auto'; // use GZIP output buffering if possible (TRUE|FALSE|'auto')
$cfg['PersistentConnections']   = FALSE;  // use persistent connections to MySQL database
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit']           = 300;    // maximum execution time in seconds (0 for no limit)
$cfg['SkipLockedTables']        = FALSE;  // mark used tables, make possible to show
                                          // locked tables (since MySQL 3.23.30)
$cfg['ShowSQL']                 = TRUE;   // show SQL queries as run
$cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase']   = FALSE;  // show a 'Drop database' link to normal users
$cfg['Confirm']                 = TRUE;   // confirm 'DROP TABLE' & 'DROP DATABASE'
$cfg['LoginCookieRecall']       = TRUE;   // recall previous login in cookie auth. mode or not
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity']     = 1440;   // validity of cookie login (in seconds)
$cfg['UseDbSearch']             = TRUE;   // whether to enable the "database search" feature
                                          // or not
$cfg['IgnoreMultiSubmitErrors'] = FALSE;  // if set to true, PMA continues computing multiple-statement queries
                                          // even if one of the queries failed
$cfg['VerboseMultiSubmit']      = TRUE;   // if set to true, PMA will show the affected rows of EACH statement on
                                          // multiple-statement queries. See the read_dump.php file for hardcoded
                                          // defaults on how many queries a statement may contain!
$cfg['AllowArbitraryServer']    = FALSE;  // allow login to any user entered server in cookie based auth

// Left frame setup
$cfg['LeftFrameLight']        = TRUE;    // use a select-based menu and display only the
                                         // current tables in the left frame.
$cfg['LeftFrameTableSeparator']= '__';   // Which string will be used to generate table prefixes
                                         // to split/nest tables into multiple categories
$cfg['LeftFrameTableLevel']   = '1';     // How many sublevels should be displayed when splitting
                                         // up tables by the above Separator
$cfg['ShowTooltip']           = TRUE;    // display table comment as tooltip in left frame
$cfg['ShowTooltipAliasDB']    = FALSE;   // if ShowToolTip is enabled, this defines that table/db comments
$cfg['ShowTooltipAliasTB']    = FALSE;   // are shown (in the left menu and db_details_structure) instead of
                                         // table/db names. Setting ShowTooltipAliasTB to 'nested' will only
                                         // use the Aliases for nested descriptors, not the table itself.

$cfg['LeftDisplayLogo']       = TRUE;   // display logo at top of left frame
$cfg['LeftDisplayServers']    = FALSE;  // display server choice at top of left frame
$cfg['DisplayServersList']    = FALSE;  // server choice as links

// In the main frame, at startup...
$cfg['ShowStats']             = TRUE;   // allow to display statistics and space usage in
                                        // the pages about database details and table
                                        // properties
$cfg['ShowMysqlInfo']         = FALSE;  // whether to display the "MySQL runtime
$cfg['ShowMysqlVars']         = FALSE;  // information", "MySQL system variables", "PHP
$cfg['ShowPhpInfo']           = FALSE;  // information" and "change password" links for
$cfg['ShowChgPassword']       = FALSE;  // simple users or not
$cfg['SuggestDBName']         = TRUE;   // suggest a new DB name if possible (false = keep empty)

// In browse mode...
$cfg['ShowBlob']              = FALSE;  // display blob field contents
$cfg['NavigationBarIconic']   = TRUE;   // do not display text inside navigation bar buttons
$cfg['ShowAll']               = FALSE;  // allows to display all the rows
$cfg['MaxRows']               = 30;     // maximum number of rows to display
$cfg['Order']                 = 'ASC';  // default for 'ORDER BY' clause (valid
                                        // values are 'ASC', 'DESC' or 'SMART' -ie
                                        // descending order for fields of type
                                        // TIME, DATE, DATETIME & TIMESTAMP,
                                        // ascending order else-)

// In edit mode...
$cfg['ProtectBinary']         = 'blob'; // disallow editing of binary fields
                                        // valid values are:
                                        //   FALSE  allow editing
                                        //   'blob' allow editing except for BLOB fields
                                        //   'all'  disallow editing
$cfg['ShowFunctionFields']    = TRUE;   // Display the function fields in edit/insert mode
$cfg['CharEditing']           = 'input';
                                        // Which editor should be used for CHAR/VARCHAR fields:
                                        //  input - allows limiting of input length
                                        //  textarea - allows newlines in fields
$cfg['InsertRows']            = 2;      // How many rows can be inserted at one time

// For the export features...
$cfg['ZipDump']               = TRUE;   // Allow the use of zip/gzip/bzip
$cfg['GZipDump']              = TRUE;   // compression for
$cfg['BZipDump']              = TRUE;   // dump files
$cfg['CompressOnFly']         = TRUE;   // Will compress gzip/bzip2 exports on
                                        // fly without need for much memory.
                                        // If you encounter problems with
                                        // created gzip/bzip2 files disable
                                        // this feature.

// Tabs display settings
$cfg['LightTabs']             = FALSE;  // use graphically less intense menu tabs
$cfg['PropertiesIconic']      = TRUE;   // Use icons instead of text for the table display of a database (TRUE|FALSE|'both')
$cfg['PropertiesNumColumns']  = 1;      // How many columns should be used for table display of a database?
                                        // (a value larger than 1 results in some information being hidden)

$cfg['DefaultTabServer']      = 'main.php';

$cfg['DefaultTabDatabase']    = 'db_details_structure.php';

$cfg['DefaultTabTable']       = 'tbl_properties_structure.php';

$cfg['MySQLManualBase'] = 'http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en';

$cfg['MySQLManualType'] = 'searchable';


/**
 * PDF options
 */
$cfg['PDFPageSizes']        = array('A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'letter', 'legal');
$cfg['PDFDefaultPageSize']  = 'A4';


/**
 * Language and charset conversion settings
 */
// Default language to use, if not browser-defined or user-defined
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'fr';
$cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$cfg['AllowAnywhereRecoding'] = FALSE;
$cfg['RecodingEngine'] = 'auto';
$cfg['IconvExtraParams'] = '';




$cfg['LeftPointerEnable']   = TRUE;         

$cfg['BrowsePointerEnable'] = TRUE;       

$cfg['BrowseMarkerEnable'] = TRUE;        

$cfg['TextareaCols']        = 40;            

$cfg['TextareaRows']        = 7;            
$cfg['LongtextDoubleTextarea'] = TRUE;      // double size of textarea size for longtext fields
$cfg['TextareaAutoSelect']  = TRUE;         // autoselect when clicking in the textarea of the querybox
$cfg['CharTextareaCols']    = 40;           // textarea size (columns) for CHAR/VARCHAR
$cfg['CharTextareaRows']    = 2;            // textarea size (rows) for CHAR/VARCHAR
$cfg['CtrlArrowsMoving']    = TRUE;         // Enable Ctrl+Arrows moving between fields when editing?
$cfg['LimitChars']          = 50;           // Max field data length in browse mode for all non-numeric fields
$cfg['ModifyDeleteAtLeft']  = TRUE;         // show edit/delete links on left side of browse
                                            // (or at the top with vertical browse)
$cfg['ModifyDeleteAtRight'] = FALSE;        // show edit/delete links on right side of browse
                                            // (or at the bottom with vertical browse)
$cfg['DefaultDisplay']      = 'horizontal'; // default display direction
                                            // (horizontal|vertical|horizontalflipped)
$cfg['DefaultPropDisplay']  = 'horizontal'; // default display direction for altering/
                                            // creating columns (tbl_properties)
                                            // (horizontal|vertical)

$cfg['HeaderFlipType']      = 'css';        // table-header rotation via faking or css? (css|fake)
                                            // NOTE: CSS only works in IE browsers!
$cfg['ShowBrowseComments']  = TRUE;         // shows stored relation-comments in 'browse' mode.
$cfg['ShowPropertyComments']= TRUE;         // shows stored relation-comments in 'table property' mode.
$cfg['RepeatCells']         = 100;          // repeat header names every X cells? (0 = deactivate)

$cfg['QueryFrame']          = TRUE;         // displays a link or icon in the left frame to open the querybox, and activates the querybox when clicking on [Edit] on the results page.
$cfg['QueryFrameJS']        = TRUE;         // whether to use JavaScript functions for opening a new window for SQL commands.
                                            // if set to 'false', the target of the querybox is always the right frame.
$cfg['QueryWindowWidth']    = 550;          // Width of Query window
$cfg['QueryWindowHeight']   = 310;          // Height of Query window
$cfg['QueryHistoryDB']      = FALSE;         // Set to TRUE if you want DB-based query history.
                                            // If FALSE, this utilizes JS-routines to display
                                            // query history (lost by window close)
$cfg['QueryWindowDefTab']   = 'sql';        // which tab to display in the querywindow on startup
                                            // (sql|files|history|full)
$cfg['QueryHistoryMax']     = 25;           // When using DB-based query history, how many entries
                                            // should be kept?
$cfg['BrowseMIME']          = TRUE;         // Use MIME-Types (stored in column comments table) for
$cfg['MaxExactCount']       = 20000;        // When approximate count < this, PMA will get exact count for
                                            // table rows.
$cfg['WYSIWYG-PDF']         = TRUE;         // Utilize DHTML/JS capabilities to allow WYSIWYG editing of
                                            // the PDF page editor. Requires an IE6/Mozilla based browser.

$cfg['NaturalOrder']        = TRUE;         // Sort table and database in natural order

$cfg['ShowHttpHostTitle']   = TRUE;            // show HttpHost in browsers window title (true|false)?
$cfg['SetHttpHostTitle']    = '';              // if ShowHttpHostTitle=true, please set your host (server)
                                             // or an other string, wich should be shown in browsers window title.
                                             // If not set (or empty), the PMA will get your real Host-Adress.

$cfg['ErrorIconic']          = TRUE;    // show some icons for warning, error and information messages (true|false)?
$cfg['MainPageIconic']       = TRUE;    // show icons in list on main page, on right panel top menu (server db table)  and on menu tabs (true|false)?
$cfg['ReplaceHelpImg']       = TRUE;    // show help button instead of strDocumentation (true|false)?

// theme manager
$cfg['ThemePath']           = './themes';    // using themes manager please set up here the path to 'themes'
                                             // else leave empty
$cfg['ThemeManager']        = TRUE;          // if you want to use selectable themes and if ThemesPath not empty
                                             // set it to true, else set it to false (default is false);
$cfg['ThemeDefault']        = 'original';         // set up default theme, if ThemePath not empty
                                             // you can set up here an valid path to themes or 'original' for
                                             // the original pma-theme

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


$cfg['DefaultQueryTable']    = 'SELECT * FROM %t WHERE 1';
$cfg['DefaultQueryDatabase'] = '';
$cfg['SQLQuery']['Edit']      = TRUE;       // Edit link to change a query
$cfg['SQLQuery']['Explain']   = TRUE;       // EXPLAIN on SELECT queries
$cfg['SQLQuery']['ShowAsPHP'] = TRUE;       // Wrap a query in PHP
$cfg['SQLQuery']['Validate']  = FALSE;      // Validate a query (see $cfg['SQLValidator'] as well)
$cfg['SQLQuery']['Refresh']   = TRUE;       // Refresh the results page

$cfg['UploadDir']             = '';         // Directory for uploaded files that can be executed by
                                            // phpMyAdmin. For example './upload'. Leave empty for
                                            // no upload directory support
$cfg['SaveDir']               = '';         // Directory where phpMyAdmin can save exported data on
                                            // server. For example './save'. Leave empty for no save
                                            // directory support.
$cfg['docSQLDir']             = '';         // Directory for docSQL imports, phpMyAdmin can import
                                            // docSQL files from that directory. For example
                                            // './docSQL'. Leave empty for no docSQL import support.
$cfg['TempDir']               = '';         // Directory where phpMyAdmin can save temporary files.
                                            // This is needed for MS Excel export, see documentation
                                            // how to enable that.

$cfg['GD2Available']          = 'auto';     

$cfg['SQP']['fmtType']      = 'html';      
$cfg['SQP']['fmtInd']       = '1';          
$cfg['SQP']['fmtIndUnit']   = 'em';         

$cfg['SQLValidator']['use']      = FALSE;  
$cfg['SQLValidator']['username'] = '';      
$cfg['SQLValidator']['password'] = '';      

$cfg['DBG']['enable'] = FALSE;              
$cfg['DBG']['profile']['enable'] = FALSE;   
$cfg['DBG']['profile']['threshold'] = 0.5; 




/**
 * Unset magic_quotes_runtime - do not change!
 */
// set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0);

$cfg['AllowThirdPartyFraming'] = TRUE;

/**
 * File Revision - do not change either!
 */
$cfg['FileRevision'] = '$Revision: 2.52 $';
?>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand, I just discovered that the internal relation pan suddently came back, without any change from me. Controluser & controlpass was still empty in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

The phpMyAdmin documentation explains that you have to do two steps: create the tables with the supplied .sql file and configure them in config.inc.php, which you did not do. In our config.sample.inc.php you can see in the "Storage database and tables" section what I mean (but these are commented out).

Comment: As I said in my question, i tried to filed these config lines, but it did not change anything. And it work without that on the other computer. I'm wondering if MAMP doesn't use an other way to store configuration for PhpMyAdmin...

Comment: After you completed these lines in config.inc.php, did you try closing and opening your browser? There is an issue where configuration lines are kept in the session, which would explain seeing no improvement after the change.

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm using this configuration for several weeks, so I even restarted my computer with no change...